# Shopware; setting the product-cover programmatically

Tags: shopware

i am trying to set the cover of a product programmatically, by doing this for example;

```
[
  "name" => "Example product"
  "price" => [
    0 => [
      "currencyId" => "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca"
      "gross" => 15
      "net" => 10
      "linked" => false
    ]
  ]
  "manufacturer" => [
    "name" => "Example manufacturer"
  ]
  "tax" => [
    "name" => "21%"
    "taxRate" => 21
  ]
  "stock" => 6235
  "productNumber" => "PE-123123"
  "coverId" => "4efd6bc156014cc2945b6351d3e9ff03"
]
```

I checked, and i am sure the media is uploaded. If i do it via the media as showed bellow, the media/image gets linked correctly.

```
"media" => [
    "Id" => 'Example",
    "mediaId" => "4efd6bc156014cc2945b6351d3e9ff03"
]
```

I don't understand why it is going wrong, as the documentation (https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/admin-api-guide/writing-entities#setting-the-cover) prescribes this way. A example in the documentation is the following;

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "productNumber": "random",
    "stock": 10,
    "taxId": "5f78f2d4b19f49648eb1b38881463da0",
    "price": [
        { "currencyId" : "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca", "gross": 15, "net": 10, "linked" : false }
    ],
    "coverId": "00a9742db2e643ccb9d969f5a30c2758"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass cover media ID in the following way:

```
[
    //other product data
    "cover" => [
        "mediaId" => "00a9742db2e643ccb9d969f5a30c2758"
    ]
]
```

For me, it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
                   "media": [
                        {
                          "id": 'YourProductUuid',
                          "media": {
                              "id": 'YourProductMediaId'
                          }
                          }
                      ],
                      "cover" : {
                                "mediaId" : 'YourProductMediaId'
                       },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).